# Bootstrap Table whenzhixin width

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

Does anyone know how to set width for a table column using that library, I tried using the getting started info, by javascript:

```
columns : [{width : "200px"}, {width : "100px"}]
```

and also tried by html

```
<th data-width="200px"></th>
```

And it's not working.

The link of the library is:
[library link](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn)

Or does anyone have another library to do similar things?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work...
http://www.codeply.com/go/AWf7gctoYv

```
        {
            field: 'name',
            title: 'Item Name',
            width: '500px'
        }
```

Comment: thanks, it's working, I guess it was a design issue.

Comment: I have found that if I take some of the things I cannot get to work into a simple codeply and isolate the parts I can get them working, then add them back in, and find out what broke it. Good luck.